# Having Trouble with Pushing nested mongodb document to an array with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm having trouble pushing nested documents to an array. Currently my code looks like this. I get that the variable categories is undefined. I feel really sad about struggling this since I resolved it at one point but my computer kicked the bucket so I'm working off of an old commit.

```
 db.collection('posts').find().toArray((err, result) => {
    var post = result.filter((post) => {
        return post.id == req.params._id
    })[0];
    var categories = [];
    for(var i=0; i > result.length; i++){
            for(var j=0;j>result[i].postCategories.length;j++){
                categories.push(result[i]postCategories[j]);
            }
        }
    categories = categories.filter( function( item, index, inputArray ) {
       return inputArray.indexOf(item) == index;
});

    res.render('admin/postedit', {
        postTitle: post.postTitle,
        postContent: post.postContent,
        postSlug: post.postSlug,
        categories: categories,
    });
});
```

Comment: There is a typo in `result[i]postCategories[j]` instead use `result[i].postCategories[j]` use `.` in between `result[i]` and `postCategories[j]`

Comment: I corrected that and I am still being returned an empty variable.

Comment: can you post the demo of raw result you are getting i.e. before filtering

Comment: result returns the two test entries i added with my post function.
    [ { _id: 5a8c34c6ead91b0a063d80ed,
    postTitle: 'test post-update-2',
    postSlug: 'test-post',
    postCategories: [ 'red', 'blank' ],
    postContent: '<p>test-post</p>' },{ _id: 5af1ae63592b520f5b227627,
    postTitle: 'rgrd',
    postSlug: 'rgrd',
    postContent: '<p>gfbngfd</p>' } ]

If you mean the categories variable still empty.

Comment: Try this `this.arr.forEach(val => {
      if(val.postCategories) {
        val.postCategories.forEach(item => {
          categories.push(item);
        })
      }
    })`

Comment: That worked brilliantly, thanks!